# Swift - APNS receive message and click to target viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have a question about APNS.

when I receive the message,and I show the WebView2 and I want to click navigation backBarButton according to my route,not back to the mainTabbarVC(index 1).

how to creat the topViewController?

```
mainTabbarVC(index1) -> mainTabbarVC(index3) -> WebView1 -> WebView2
```

receive APNS and back

```
WebView2 -> WebView1 -> MainTabbarVC(index3)
```

Comment: you need to use mainTabbarVC(index3) while apns arrives .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let yourNaviagtionController = tabBarController.customizableViewControllers?[3]// reference of your navigation controller at index 3 
// now push your viewcontroller in this navigationController
```

Comment: hello KKRocks, how to use your suggestion in appDelegate.swift.Because I receive notification function write in appDelegate.

Comment: yes you can use this in appdelgate....you need to get reference of tabbarviewcontroller in appdelegate.